# C++: call original definition of operator equals

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, equals-operator

I am overloading the operator equals (==) as show bellow:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool operator == (std::string str1, std::string str2) {
    std::transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2.begin(), ::tolower);
    return (str1 == str2);
}
```

but, the problem appear on line return (str1 == str2), because operator == is called recursively. So, **how can I call the original definition for operator equals** (not the overloaded) ?

Best regards

Comment: This isn't permitted by the standard. You can't overload operators for standard types.

Comment: @chris: I think you can, as long as you don't place it in namespace `std`. That's not necessarily the best idea, of course.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I'm pretty sure I've had this discussion and arrived at can't because the standard says so. Of course it's possible as long as the compiler lets you (I can get this working on Clang).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Ah, found it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10469991#10469991

Comment: @chris: I looked at that discussion, but it doesn't seem to cite chapter and verse. I couldn't find such a prohibition in `17.6.4 Constraints on programs`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @chris \[citation needed\]. Where is this in the standard? I can only find a prohibition against defining stuff in std::.

Comment: Even if it is allowed. Its not a good idea. This is probably the wrong solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I'm not sure, I'm mostly going off of another's expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return std::operator==(str1, str2);
```

or

```
return (str1.compare(str2) == 0);
```

Though I suspect you'll have ambiguous overload error, between your `operator==` found by ordinary lookup, and `std::operator==` found by argument-dependent lookup. In any case, attempting to change the meaning of `str1 == str2` may not be the best idea; if nothing else, it violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 0):

```
return (str1 == str2);

to------->

if( 0 == str1.compare(str2))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```